# How to disable or reset value inside its property changed

Tags: binding

Hi I am developing mvvm wpf application , my problem is when user select some item in combobox I am asking a question to user yes/no, if user selects no i want to reset the value to previous selected item.. I am able to reset it and its value getting updated .. but the problem is the old value which i am setting is inside property changed event which is not getting updated in UI (Since I am doing it inside Property changed , i guess). Is there any work around or solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your VM implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), and then make sure that the property whose old value you are resetting sends a notification when its value changes.  Binding will then take care of updating the bound control.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public object PropertyToReset 
    {  
        get { return _propertyToReset; } 
        set
        {
            if (_propertyToReset == value) { return; }
            // capture the old value in case the user decides not to change the value
            _oldPropertyToResetValue = _propertyToReset;
            _propertyToReset = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("PropertyToReset");
        } 
    }

    public bool IsPropertyChanging
    {
        get { _isPropertyChanging; }
        set
        {
            if (_isPropertyChanging == value) { return; }
            _isPropertyChanging = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsPropertyChanging");
            if (value == false) { PropertyToReset = _oldPropertyToResetValue; }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```